# Select from db and limit result to where datetime is the same

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a datetime field in my db. Now i want to select upcoming dates from NOW() based on the dates. If two datetimes is the same I want to select them. And if it's only one I want to select that date. Limit is that I never want to select more than two rows.
So if NOW() is *2021-06-18 12:00:00* row number **1** should be selected.
If NOW() is *2021-06-20 18:15:00* row number **3 and 4** should be selected.

```
  1  2021-06-19 18:00:00
  2  2021-06-20 18:00:00
  3  2021-06-21 15:00:00
  4  2021-06-21 15:00:00
  5  2021-06-21 18:00:00
  6  2021-06-21 18:00:00
```

I've tried

```
SELECT gamedate 
FROM games 
WHERE gamedate > NOW() 
ORDER BY gamedate LIMIT 0 , 1
```

but that doesn't make any sense or what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the next gamedate. Then use that in the main query to select at most two rows with that date.

```
SELECT id, gamedate
FROM games AS g
WHERE gamemedate = (SELECT MIN(gamedate) FROM games WHERE gamedate > NOW())
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 2
```